# How to download a pdf that opens in a new tab in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a page with a button. When I click that button, it opens a PDF in a new tab.

How can I download the PDF as a file with puppeteer?

Maybe I can write a file with the buffer from the new tab. But I am not sure how.

Answer (score 5):

Use puppeteer-extra node module.

[Puppeteer-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra?activeTab=readme)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
...
...
puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences')({userPrefs: {
   download: {
     prompt_for_download: false,
     open_pdf_in_system_reader: true
  },
  plugins: {
    always_open_pdf_externally: true // this should do the trick
  }
}}))

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

browser.on('targetcreated', async (target) => {
   console.log('targetcreated');
   if (target.type() !== 'page') {
     return;
   }
   try {
     const pageList = await browser.pages();
     pageList.forEach((page) => {
       page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
         behavior: 'allow',
         downloadPath: './pdfDownloaded/',
       });
     });
   } catch (e) {
     console.log("targetcreated", e);
   }
});
...
...
```

But when i set the `always_open_pdf_externally: true` chrome crashes.

try if it works for you, and please post back the answer if you found any

Comment: `page._client` is not function in new versions of puppeteer

Comment: Yes, the page._client doesn't exist anymore but you can now use it like this :

    
page.target().createCDPSession()  // ( createCDPSession === page._client)

Comment: I've been looking for this for a long time. It was the only solution that worked for me, in days.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use the `fetch` api to execute the `GET` request. This way you can read the response, pass it to your backend and save it to disk.

Use this sample code as reference:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

async function downloadImage(page: any, url: string, fullpath: string) {
  const data = await page.evaluate(
    // tslint:disable-next-line no-shadowed-variable
    async ({ url }) => {
      function readAsBinaryStringAsync(blob) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const fr = new FileReader();
          fr.readAsBinaryString(blob);
          fr.onload = () => {
            resolve(fr.result);
          };
        });
      }

      const r = await fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp, */*;q=0.8',
          'cache-control': 'no-cache',
          pragma: 'no-cache',
          'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
          'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
          'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
        },
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer-when-downgrade',
        body: null,
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors'
      });

      return await readAsBinaryStringAsync(await r.blob());
    },
    { url }
  );

  fs.writeFileSync(fullpath, data, { encoding: 'binary' });
}
```