Downloading invoices that open in another tab with puppeteer and expressjs
I'm trying to make a invoice scraper that downloads the invoices off a website. The issue I am having is the invoices open up into a new tab, I believe this is a chromium behavior. I've switched over to puppeteer-extra and tried a few solutions that others have found on stackoverflow. However, nothing has worked and I believe it may be because of how I've structured everything. My current structure is that I have a browser manager utility class that instantiates an instance and holds it throughout the program, it works well for navigating the pages and keeping a separation of concerns in my project. Through my controller I call on methods within the utility class, it also ensures there is only one instance of a browser.
Here's what that looks like:
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
import { Browser, Page } from "puppeteer";

class BrowserManager {
  
  ...rest of methods

  public async initialize(
    username: string,
    password: string,
    url: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    if (this.isInitialized) {
      console.log("Browser session already initialized");
      return;
    }

    try {
      puppeteer.use(
        require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences")({
          headless: false,
          timeout: 30000,
          ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
          userPrefs: {
            download: {
              prompt_for_download: false,
              open_pdf_in_system_reader: true,
            },
            plugins: {
              always_open_pdf_externally: true,
            },
          },
        })
      );

      this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
      });

      this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
      await this.page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
        timeout: 30000,
      });

      await this.page.waitForSelector("#loginForm");
      await this.page.type("#UserName", username);
      await this.page.type("#Password", password);
      await this.page.click('input[name="login"]');

      await this.page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
        timeout: 30000,
      });

      await this.page.waitForSelector(".select-account");

      this.isInitialized = true;
      console.log("Browser session initialized successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Could not initialize browser session:", error);
      await this.cleanup();
      throw error;
    }
  }
  ... rest of methods.
}

export default BrowserManager;

There is no link directly to the pdf, everything is server-side and embedded within the main page, so I can't download it just from the link. Within my controller I'm having to click on the element, for some reason using page.goto() was not working.
Here's what my controller looks like:

export const alscoDownloadInvoiceController = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    const { invoiceUrl } = req.query;

    const browserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
    const page = await browserManager.getPage();
    const client = await page.createCDPSession();

    console.log("Client created.");

    await client.send("Browser.setDownloadBehavior", {
      behavior: "allow",
      downloadPath: "./downloads",
      eventsEnabled: true,
    });

    console.log("Download behavior set");

    await page.click(`a[href="${invoiceUrl}"]`);

    await setTimeout(3000);

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Downloaded invoice.",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to download invoice: ", error);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: "Failed to download invoice.",
      message: error,
    });
  }
};

That's the current download controller I have so far, I've tried a few other solutions, but I still have not been able to download the invoices. I imagine that separating out the logic into a utility class complicates things, but even then I am completely unsure on how to do this.

There's a few different ways to handle logins, if a manual login is required, you could try saving the cookies and then setting the cookies before you launch the script.

Ya I'm having no issues logging in, it's just how chromium opens up a new tab when clicking on a link to an embedded pdf. I am unable to download the pdf, even if I try to intercept it with puppeteers built in functions. @r_2009

@r_2009 Apologies, I edited the post to reflect what I'm looking for and removed most of the unnecessary code. I'm just frazzled on how to do this, it seems like this is a common problem with puppeteer and chromium, I just haven't found a work-around for my use case.

there's another question here that might contain the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804931/how-to-download-a-pdf-that-opens-in-a-new-tab-in-puppeteer

@r_2009 Yeah I've tried this answer, I even have the puppeteer-extra plugin, for some reason it won't work with my code. I know that the _client() function no longer works so I had to use the newer method, but even then I was unable to get the pdf to download.

Try using an absolute path: __dirname + '/downloads'
